# Excel conditional formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a formula dependent on the value of cell U2

If it is between 20 and 24
set cell V2 = "20-24 EE"

or

If it is between 25 and 29
set cell V2 = "25-29 EE"

or

If it is between 30 and 35
set cell V2 = "30-35 EE"

Comment: Are we talking integers only? By "between 20 and 24" do mean "larger or equal to 20 and smaller or equal to 24"?

Comment: I mean larger or equal to 20 and smaller or equal to 24.

Comment: Questions about Excel, such as this one, would be so much cleaner if SuperUser had TeX/MathJax.  I'm hoping that StackExchange might consider adopting MathJax more widely in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula in V2:

`=IF(AND($U$2>=20,$U$2<=24),"20-24 EE",IF(AND($U$2>=25,$U$2<=29),"25-29 EE",IF(AND($U$2>=30,$U$2<=35),"30-35 EE","Error")))`

This will return "20-24 EE", "25-29 EE", or "30-35 EE" for integer values in the respective range. It will return "Error" for non-integer values or integers less than 20 or greater than 35.

Comment: Hello! Can you give me the formula for the below! I tried to use the above format but I kept getting an error.

Comment: If cell f2 says "Core State Inc. - USA Semi-Monthly 1" then I want 000 to be entered into the cell                                                                                     If cell f2 says "Core States Construction Services - USA Semi-Monthly 2" then I want 001 to be entered into the cell                            If cell f2 says "Integrated Images" then I want 002 to be entered into the cell

Thank you,

Comment: For that scenario, use the following:

'=IF($F$2="Core State Inc. - USA Semi-Monthly 1","000",IF($F$2="Core States Construction Services - USA Semi-Monthly 2","001",IF($F$2="Integrated Images","002","Error")))'

I assumed an absolute reference for F2, but you might have to adjust that depending on how you're using your spreadsheet. Note: Setting up the formula in this manner (using an if/else cascade) works well enough for small amounts of data and a small number of cases (yours had 3). If you plan on adding more than 3 ranges to check, you should definitely use cybernetic.nomad's method.

Comment: Thank you! You’ve been a great help!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are dealing with integers only, you can use `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX({"","20-24 ""","25-29 EE","30-35 EE",""},MATCH(U2,{0,20,25,29,35,10000000},1))
```

NB: The formula will return `""` if the number is less than 20 or more than 35

Comment: Hello the numbers in cell u2 are ages. I have to turn them into ranges so for people who are aged 20-24, I need it to enter in 20-24 EE and if they are aged between 25-29, I need it to enter in 25-29 EE and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a different approach, because this IS the use case for which `VLOOKUP` is designed. `INDEX` `MATCH` is indubitably more powerful, but it's needlessly complex here.

### Solution

[image: sample data]

### 1. Create and name your lookup table

I put the lookup table in `X:Y`. It can be a different sheet or workbook altogether, if you like. Put your delimiters in the first column and the group names you want in the second column. Highlight the table (no headers) and select 'Define Name':

[image: lookup table]

### 2. Formula

`=VLOOKUP(U2,groups,2,TRUE)`

Copy that formula into `V2`. That formula copies down.

This says look up `U2` in the table called `groups` (you could also skip step 1 and give this function a range in the form of cell references, `X2:Y6` in this case), and bring back the value from the `2`nd column. The `TRUE` argument is what makes it work as a lookup table.

### NB.

This is dead easy, as, again, it's exactly why `VLOOKUP` exists. The advantage of using a lookup table over a series of nested `IF`s or an `INDEX` `MATCH` array formula (both totally viable solutions for this request) is 1) its ease of use due to the simplicity of the formula itself, but even more importantly 2) its flexibility moving forward. If the groupings change, or the group names change, or you need MORE groups or fewer, all you have to do is change the values in the lookup table; no formula entry is required at all.

Comment: There's something unsatisfying about needing to build an extra table on the spreadsheet, as recommended by this answer.  As a consequence, I suspect that a lot of users wouldn't like this approach.  Still, this approach seems a lot more maintainable, legible, and just generally well-constructed.  As such, I probably wouldn't bother doing it this way for a quick calculation that's just going to be tossed anyway, but for creating a professional spreadsheet that'll endure and be shared, this seems like the way to go.

Comment: @Nat I totally agree. If I needed a one-off and was doing it myself for myself, there's zero chance I'd set it up this way. Probably three `IF`s and definitely fewer, I'd just write nested `IF`s; more than that and I'd use the `INDEX` `MATCH` with arrays. Almost exactly how the other two answers here have it. I thought it'd be nice to present the entire range of approaches - and, as you say, if the use case calls for repeated use, or other people as users, this is *definitely* the way to go.

Comment: @Tie very happy to help. Out of curiosity, what solution did you go with, and how has it worked out for you?

Comment: I used =IF(AND($U$2>=20,$U$2<=24),"20-24 EE",IF(AND($U$2>=25,$U$2<=29),"25-29 EE",IF(AND($U$2>=30,$U$2<=35),"30-35 EE","Error")))

Comment: @Tie Cool! Glad that helped. Please consider selecting that user's answer as the correct one, so this question can be marked complete and removed from the unanswered queue.